# Using Different Parameters in Same excel Workbook for SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, excel-2016

I have an excel Workbook with 2 sheets.
In each sheet I have a Query that extracts data from an external Server through SQLserver.

in Sheet1, Cell A1, I have the value 1000

and starting from Cell B2 I need the Query to get all the Students that have score more than 1000

I write the code in Excel in Data > Connection Properties > Definition > Command text

My code goes as follows:

```
SELECT Results.ID, Results.Score
FROM Results
Where Results.Score > ?
```

When I press OK, I am prompted to select a cell to be used as a parameter instead of the '?' Character

and then I get all Students ID & Score of Students with score more than 1000

and when I change the Cell A1 in Sheet1

Now in Sheet2, Cell A1, I have the Value 5
and starting from Cell B2 I need the Query to get all students in Grade 5

My code goes as follows:

```
SELECT Students.ID, Students.Grade
FROM Students
WHERE Students.Grade = ?
```

and When I press ok, the query runs without asking me to assign cell to hold the '?' Parameter , and it uses the parameter from the first query

How can I tell excel that I need a different parameter for each Query

Thanks in advance

Comment: let's see what you have

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't get your comment
Do you need more clarification ?

Comment: Here, this will explain I mean: [mcve]  ...  you're missing the "complete" and "verifiable" parts.  :-)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see the notification for your comment.
I rephrased the question and I tried to be more Complete :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I searched a lot for anyone who have the same problem as me and I could't find So I thought it must be something I am doing to cause the problem

To facilitate creating the second query, I used to make a replicate of the 1st sheet and change the SQL command of the 2nd Query in the 2nd Sheet, which I found causes the replication of the parameter used

So the solution is simply create new query for each new Sheet